# Connect timeout Net::LDAP в скрипте на Perl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, perl, ldap, timeout

Имеется скрипт, который подключается к КД для получения информации о пользователе. Под тестовой машиной на Win он отрабатывает нормально, но на сервере с Ubuntu 14.04 он завершается по таймауту подключения.
Подключение описано следующим куском кода:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::LDAP;

<..code..>

my $server = "dc.domain.loc";
my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new( $server ) or die $@;
$ldap->bind ('read@domain.loc',
    password => 'passwd'

    );
my $result = $ldap->search(
base   => "dc=domain,dc=loc",
scope => "subtree",
filter => "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=Person) (sAMAccountName=$user))",
);

die $result->error if $result->code;

foreach my $entry ($result->entries) {
    $FIO=$entry->get_value("displayName"),
    ($umail=$entry->get_value("mail") || '');
}

$ldap->unbind;

<code...>
```

Ошибка появляется следующая:

```
IO::Socket::INET6: connect: timeout at config.pl line 35, <DATA> line 755.
```

35 строка как раз инициализация подключения к КД

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда смотреть и как исправить данную проблему. т.к. Perl совсем не знаю.

P.S.:

```
$perl -v

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

P.P.S.: доступ до КД с данного сервера есть, IPv6 отключен.
Скрипт брал тут: https://okiru.ru/automation/thunderbird-autoconf-with-ad/

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно добавить проверку `$ldap->bind(...) or die;` и потом еще посмотреть логи на Ubuntu

Comment: @AlexanderFarber, вопрос скорее не в добавлении проверки, а в том, почему он не подключается к КД.
И где можно логи посмотреть, может подскажете?
Попытался прогнать с дебагом - ничего подозрительного не заметил, к сожалению.

Comment: grep -ri ldap /var/log

Comment: 1. *INET6* — хождение `ipv6` у вас в сети нормально реализовано?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, специально написал в вопросе, что IPv6 отключено на сервере. Меня и самого смущает именно эта строка, но, как я понимаю, данная библиотека (?) реализует не только IPv6, но и IPv4

Comment: @AlexanderFarber, в логах никаких ошибок и предупреждений нет. Завтра попробую поснифать трафик на КД и данной linux машине, т.к. snmpwalk так же отказывается на ней работать

Comment: да, наверняка. и, скорее всего, ей можно об этом сказать. смотрите в `man Net::LDAP`: там средий опций при создании объекта можно указать и `inet6`. подозреваю, что примерно так: `Net::LDAP->new( $server, inet6 => 0 )`. если не поможет, убедитесь, что ipv6 **действительно** отключен. см. вывод команды `ip a` — там не должно быть упоминаний про `inet6`.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена.
Крылась она в типе сетевого адаптера, установленного для ВМ (ESXi). Изначально стоял E1000, после смены на VMXNET3 скрипт стал нормально отрабатывать. При выставлении обратно в E1000 - скрипт не выполнялся и завершался по таймауту соединения с КД.

Пока на эту тему не гуглил и не углублялся, поэтому точных причин назвать, к сожалению, не могу.